# Is there any way to pass an annotation's values to my config in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-config

I have a config and it's `@Import`-ed by an annotation. I want the values on the annotation to be accessible by the config. Is this possible?

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig
{
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager)
    {
        //Get the values in here

        return new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehcache() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        ehCacheManagerFactoryBean.setShared(true);

        return ehCacheManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

The annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Import(MyConfig.class)
public @interface EnableMyCaches
{
    String value() default "";
    String cacheName() default "my-cache";
}
```

How would I get the value passed below in my config?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMyCaches(cacheName = "the-cache")
public class MyServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple Java reflection:

```
Class c = MyServiceApplication.getClass();
EnableMyCaches enableMyCaches = c.getAnnotation(EnableMyCaches.class);
String value = enableMyCaches.value();
```

Comment: This requires my code to know beforehand the name of the class with my annotation. But if my class is include as a dependency jar I can't know that

Answer (score 1):

Consider how things like [`@EnableConfigurationProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/EnableConfigurationProperties.java) are implemented.

The annotation has `@Import(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.class)` [which](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java) then imports [`ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/a0bce618c2f51d8af1fc00ee2c3868ba2c8e0045/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java)s. These registrars are passed annotation metadata:

```
public interface ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {

    public void registerBeanDefinitions(
            AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry);

}
```

You can then get annotation attributes from annotation metadata:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> attributes = metadata
                .getAllAnnotationAttributes(
                        EnableMyCaches.class.getName(), false);
attributes.get("cacheName");
```